# Why doesn't OpenSSH work but paramiko does when using ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, paramiko, openssh

I am running `ansible-playbook` with

```bash
ansible-playbook -u vagrant -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml -c ssh
```

This throws error `fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ", "unreachable": true}`

However, it works fine after adding connection flag `-c paramiko`.

```bash
ansible-playbook -u vagrant -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml -c paramiko
```

Question: what could be the reasons the default connection (OpenSSH) does not work but paramiko does? How can I debug it and make OpenSSH works too?

I would like to understand the reasons. Please let me know if you need more information other than

- local: ubuntu 20.04
- remote: CentOS 7
- ansible [core 2.13.6]

When running with verbose mode

```bash
ansible-playbook -u vagrant -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory playbook.yml -c ssh -vvv
```

The output is

```bash
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py:236: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Blowfish has been deprecated
  "class": algorithms.Blowfish,
ansible-playbook [core 2.13.6]
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/john/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /home/john/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/john/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 3.10.6 (main, Nov  2 2022, 18:53:38) [GCC 11.3.0]
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /home/john/test/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /home/john/test/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /home/john/test/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /home/john/test/.vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory inventory source with ini plugin
Skipping callback 'default', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'minimal', as we already have a stdout callback.
Skipping callback 'oneline', as we already have a stdout callback.

PLAYBOOK: playbook.yml *************************************************************************************************
1 plays in playbook.yml

PLAY [all] *************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/john/test/playbook.yml:2
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: vagrant
<127.0.0.1> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o Port=2222 -o 'IdentityFile="/home/john/test/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="vagrant"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o 'ControlPath="/home/john/.ansible/cp/055b8f4af0"' 127.0.0.1 '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~vagrant && sleep 0'"'"''
<127.0.0.1> (255, b'/home/vagrant\n', b'')
fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ",
    "unreachable": true
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************
default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: What is the output if you run ansible with `-vvv`

Comment: I have edited my question to include the verbose output. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The command that Ansible is running is returning 255 as the return code, for some reason:

```
<127.0.0.1> (255, b'/home/vagrant\n', b'')
```

OpenSSH uses this return code for connection errors but does not prevent remote processes from returning it, and Ansible can't tell the difference between a 255 that is a genuine connection error and whatever happened here.

Paramiko is a Python library and raises errors using native Python error handling, so it doesn't have the same issue.

The only way to get Ansible's OpenSSH plugin working is to figure out why `'/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~vagrant && sleep 0'"'"'` is returning 255 on your target host, and fix that issue.